# TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'length'

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Flask приложение. Создаю модель таблицы базы данных. Использую MySQL

```
class Tomato(db.Model):
    ...
    variety = db.Column(db.Unicode, length=100, nullable=False)
    ...
```

Получаю ошибку

```
>>> TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'length'
```

Если написать

```
class Tomato(db.Model):
    ...
    variety = db.Column(db.Unicode, mysql_length=100, nullable=False)
    ...
```

```
>>> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Argument 'mysql_length' is not accepted by dialect 'mysql' on behalf of <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Column'>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
variety = db.Column(db.Unicode(100), nullable=False)
```

---

**P.S.**

Если вы хотите установить `nullable=True` для поля модели, то можно вообще не указывать длину: 
(`nullable` установлен в `True` по умолчанию, и значит его тоже не надо указывать)

```
variety = db.Column(db.Unicode)
```